# Do you need permission to check the device id in iOS?

Tags: ios, device, identifier

I'm retrieving my iPod Touch's device id in my app so I can run the full version on my device without purchasing it (this is let me retain me the capability to check both purchased and non-purchased versions).

The retrieval works fine on my device under the developer's license, but my question is, will there be a problem with permissions or anything once it's running on someone else device after having been downloaded from the app store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the UDID, but they've indicated that that access is deprecated, so may disappear at some future point

http://ios5source.com/2011/08/19/udid-deprecated-who-is-screwed/